# How can I get text from an A tag with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, text, getattribute

I have been trying to scrape some products online, but when I try and print the title from an A tag it gives me this output:

> <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="48e7924c296324a7a5a843d9ccab36fb", element="b8871651-23af-42c6-a49a-5b93fe932653")>

Now this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://egypt.souq.com")

dotd = "/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/img"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(dotd).click()

def get_deals():
    title_xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h6/span/a"
    titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(title_xpath)
    for title in titles:
        print(title)

get_deals()
print("successful")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output from `print()`...

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="48e7924c296324a7a5a843d9ccab36fb", element="b8871651-23af-42c6-a49a-5b93fe932653")>
```

...isn’t any error, but the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) itself.

---

It seems you were close. As you were able to extract the element, to extract the *text* within the element, you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  for title in titles:
      print(title.text)
  ```
- Using `get_attribute()` attribute:

  ```
  for title in titles:
      print(title.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: It **worked!** but it is only printing one title, even though the page has multiple titles

Comment: @RazerPYOfficial Glad to be able to help you. But this sounds to be a different issue all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: I posted another question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing the **object**, which contains all the properties, instead of the **text property**.

So, the only thing that you need to change is, instead of using `print(title)`, use `print(title.text)`